# How to view a list of databases under server in SQL Anywhere like we do in SQL Server

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere

I am very new to SQL Anywhere. I have been working with SQL Server for a long time.

In SQL Server, if we need to see the list of database under server, we can see that under Server Explorer.

How can I do same in SQL Anywhere?

I have just installed SQL Anywhere 16 and have no idea how to find Server name etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a database and then start the database server.

On installation of SQL Anywhere it does not automatically setup a database server/service.

Once it is running, you can connect as DBA to it with SQL Central or other tools.